# Why can I construct a istreambuf_iterator from a const istream using rdbuf()?

Tags: c++, constants, iostream

For some reason this isn't allowed:

```cpp
void foo(const std::istream& bar) { std::istreambuf_iterator<char> baz(bar); }
```

but this is allowed:

```cpp
void foo(const std::istream& bar) { std::istreambuf_iterator<char> baz(bar.rdbuf()); }
void foo(std::istream&& bar) { std::istreambuf_iterator<char> baz(bar); }
```

Seems like a bizarre design choice. All that `istreambuf_iterator` does is manipulate the `rdbuf()`, access of which is `const`, yet you can only construct a `istreambuf_iterator` from a non-`const` `istream`. Depending on what counts as "mutating the `istream`", shouldn't either `rdbuf()` be non-`const` or `istreambuf_iterator` take a `const istream`?

Comment: I'm not sure the question matches the evidence. You show that you can't construct with a *const* `istream` reference, rather than the opposite. This is correct as the `istream` does not provide the necessary `const` member functions for the iterator to operate over a `const` instance.

Comment: The title was incorrect; I edited it.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to ask why `rdbuf` returns a non-`const` reference to a part of a `const` object. Or something like that.

Comment: I think @anatolyg is suggesting the same, but you shouldn't be able to do what you are asking, right? The iterator mutates underlying state as shown in [the example, here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)

Comment: Yeah, the question should probably be the other way around.

Comment: I edited the title according to what I think is more interesting to ask.